# How to setup the direct optical fiber cable internet connection using media converter (Tp-link MC110CS)

Tags: networking

I have an optical fiber internet connection. They spliced and joined one side of the SC with the optical fiber cable and the other end of the SC to the modem (**Huawei EchoLife EG8141A5**).and also they configured a new wlan setup in the modem and its working fine.
Now my modem is not working. So I bought a **TP-Link Archer C6** modem and a **TP-Link MC110CS** media converter. How to configure this modem with these components.!

I connected the SC port from the optical cable to the TX port, I connected the RJ45 cable and the other end to the modem from the media converter, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The media converter (or SFP module) needs to match the optical line's protocol.

The  TP-Link MC110CS uses 100BASE-FX which isn't likely to be used. 1000BASE-LX (dual fiber) or 1000BASE-BX10 (single fiber) is much more likely - both won't work with your converter.

Also possible is a GPON variant (single fiber generally) which you'd need to ask your ISP about. GPON won't work with a simple media converter but requires an compatible ONT. *If* it is GPON you should *never* connect a TX port from any other variant to it - depending on the exact wavelengths, you might be seriously interrupting transmissions from a whole ODN group.

Also with fiber, you need to take care of using a correct connector: PC/SPC/UPC (grey or blue SC connector) are interchangeable (flat end face), but a **green connector** indicates an angled end face and must be matched at all times. Using a flat end-face connector in an APC jack (or vice versa) can permanently damage the end faces, requiring replacement.

Comment: I have just checked the old modem ( Huawei EchoLife EG8141A5 ) It uses the GPON technology. Can you suggest any convertor or any device to Make it work

Comment: Sorry, product recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: Ok sorry for that